# if statement not working (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

This `if` statement results in a mix of fixed jobs and other results that should not be returned. Can't figure out why something so simple isn't working.

```
if($item["total_spent"] >= '1000' 
    && ($item["country"] == 'United States' || $item["country"] == 'Canada')
    && ($item["job_duration"] == '3 to 6 months' || $item["job_duration"] = 'More than 6 months') 
    && ($item["job_engagement"] == 'Full-time - 30+ hrs/week' || $item["job_engagement"] = 'Part-time - 10-30 hrs/week') 
    && ($item["job_type"] == 'Hourly') )
```

Comment: you have single = in some instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, what you mean is this:

```
if($item["total_spent"] >= '1000' 
        && ($item["country"] == 'United States' || $item["country"] == 'Canada')
        && ($item["job_duration"] == '3 to 6 months' || $item["job_duration"] == 'More than 6 months') 
        && ($item["job_engagement"] == 'Full-time - 30+ hrs/week' || $item["job_engagement"] == 'Part-time - 10-30 hrs/week') 
        && ($item["job_type"] == 'Hourly') )
```

Notice the use of single `=` in some your where clauses

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a couple of accidental assignments in the code, does the following work?

```
<?php
if($item["total_spent"] >= '1000' 
            && ($item["country"] == 'United States' || $item["country"] == 'Canada')
            && ($item["job_duration"] == '3 to 6 months' || $item["job_duration"] == 'More than 6 months') 
            && ($item["job_engagement"] == 'Full-time - 30+ hrs/week' || $item["job_engagement"] == 'Part-time - 10-30 hrs/week') 
            && ($item["job_type"] == 'Hourly')
) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$item["job_engagement"] = 'Part-time - 10-30 hrs/week'
$item["job_duration"] = 'More than 6 months'
```

These lines are wrote as if you are assigning values, they should be:

```
$item["job_engagement"] == 'Part-time - 10-30 hrs/week'
$item["job_duration"] == 'More than 6 months'
```